Scrolling Down RecycleView Bug
When running the app on android, the first time scrolling down for about 1000 widgets in RecycleView, I can see the height changes real time (btw i make the height of parent widgets to adjust dynamically) because the text input by user are sometimes too long. It makes the app laggy while adjusting it's height specially on low end mobile devices.
KV FILE:
<CustomCard>:

    spacing: dp(10)
    padding: dp(10)

    # Add a canvas for background color
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (230/255, 227/255, 235/255, 1)  # Set your desired background color here
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [15]

    MDFloatLayout:
        size_hint_x: .01
        size_hint_y: 1
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .02, "center_y": .5}

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (2/255, 120/255, 3/255, 1) if root.sent_at else (255/255, 242/255, 0, 1) if root.latitude and root.longitude else (0.925, 0.122, 0.149, 1)
            RoundedRectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                radius: [5, 5, 5, 5]

    MyBoxLayout:
        id: boxer
        spacing: dp(2)
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        orientation: "vertical"

        Label:
            text: f"[{root.widget_count} of {root.total_count}]: {root.reference_number}"
            font_size: "15sp"
            color:"black"
            bold: True
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            text_size: self.width, None
            on_size:
                self.texture_update()
                self.height = self.texture_size[1]

        Label:
            text: "Remarks:"
            bold: True
            font_size:"14sp"
            color:"#666666"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1] if root.remarks else 0
            text_size: self.width, None
            opacity: 1 if root.remarks else 0
            on_size:
                self.texture_update()
                self.height = self.texture_size[1] if root.remarks else 0

        Label:
            text: root.remarks if root.remarks else "<None>"
            font_size:"14sp"
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1] if root.remarks else 0
            text_size: self.width, None
            opacity: 1 if root.remarks else 0
            on_size:
                self.texture_update()
                self.height = self.texture_size[1] if root.remarks else 0



        MDButton:
            style: 'text'
            height: "15dp" if root.image_count > 0 else 0
            size_hint_x: .3
            opacity: 1 if root.image_count > 0 else 0
            MDButtonIcon:
                icon: 'image'
                x: 1
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                icon_color: "black"
            MDButtonText:
                text: f"{root.image_count} Image(s) transmitted" if root.sent_picture == 1 else (f"{root.image_count} Image(s)" if root.image_count > 0 else "0 Image")
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: "black"
                font_style: "Body"
                role: "medium"

        Label:
            text: f"Transmitted successfully: [color=#008000]{root.sent_at}[/color]" if root.sent_at else ("Status: Ready to transmit" if (root.latitude and root.longitude) else "Status: Location not found")
            bold: True
            font_size: "13sp"
            color: "#666666"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            text_size: self.width, None
            markup: True
            on_size:
                self.texture_update()
                self.height = self.texture_size[1]


    Label:
        text: root.event_type
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.8}
        font_name: "f2icons/status.ttf"
        color: "#FFF200"
        font_size: "19sp"
        size_hint_x: None
        size: self.texture_size

MDScreen:
    on_enter: app.apply_colors_based_on_mode()
    name: 'main'
    md_bg_color: "#FFF200"
    MDNavigationLayout:
        MDScreenManager:

            MDScreen:

                # RecycleView section
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        padding: "10dp"

                       
                        RecycleView:
                            id: card_list
                            viewclass: "CustomCard"
                            do_scroll_x: False
                            effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
                            RecycleBoxLayout:
                                orientation: 'vertical'
                                spacing: dp(15)
                                size_hint_y: None
                                size: self.minimum_size
                                default_size_hint: 1, None
                                # magic value for the default height of the message
                                default_size: 0, 38
                                


                    # Bottom navigation bar
                    MDBottomAppBar:
                        id: bottom_nav
                        theme_bg_color: "Custom"
                        #allow_hidden: True
                        #scroll_cls: card_list
                        action_items:[]

                        MDFabBottomAppBarButton:
                            id: fab
                            icon: "plus"
                            theme_bg_color: "Custom"
                            md_bg_color: "#FFF200"
                            theme_text_color: "Custom"
                            text_color: "black"
                            on_release: app.new_event()

PY FILE:
class CustomCard(BoxLayout, RecycleDataViewBehavior):
    # Your properties and methods
    fixed_height = NumericProperty(100)
    event_id = NumericProperty()
    widget_count = NumericProperty()
    total_count = NumericProperty()
    event_type = StringProperty()
    reference_number = StringProperty()
    remarks = StringProperty()
    image_count = NumericProperty(0)
    latitude = NumericProperty()
    longitude = NumericProperty()
    image_path = StringProperty(defaultvalue='')
    created_at = StringProperty()
    sent_at = StringProperty(defaultvalue='')  # Add this line
    sent_picture = NumericProperty(0)
    index = 0

    def update_card_height(self, *args):
        total_height = 0
        for child in self.children:
            if child.size_hint_y is None:
                total_height += child.height
        self.height = total_height + dp(50)

        # Force the RecycleView to refresh the view
        if self.parent and hasattr(self.parent, 'refresh_from_data'):
            self.parent.refresh_from_data()

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.index = index
        self.event_id = int(data.get('event_id', 0))
        self.widget_count = data.get('widget_count', 0)
        self.event_type = data.get('event_type', '')
        self.reference_number = data.get('reference_number', '')
        self.remarks = data.get('remarks', '')
        self.image_count = data.get('image_count', 0)
        self.latitude = float(data.get('latitude', 0.0))
        self.longitude = float(data.get('longitude', 0.0))
        self.image_path = data.get('image_path', '')
        self.created_at = self.remarks = data.get('created_at', '')
        self.sent_at = data.get('sent_at', '') or ''
        self.sent_picture = int(data.get('event_id', 0))
        super(CustomCard, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.update_card_height)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            # Only call on_release if the touch was actually within the card
            if touch.is_mouse_scrolling:
                return False  # Ignore scroll events
            app = MDApp.get_running_app()
            print(f"Event ID on release: {self.event_id}")
            app.display_event_details(self.event_id)
            return True
        return super().on_touch_up(touch)

class MainFunction(MDApp):

        def add_main_widgets(self):
        def fetch_data_thread():
            events_data = self.fetch_data_from_db1()
            self.update_ui_with_data(events_data)
            self.cleanup_expired_events()

        Thread(target=fetch_data_thread).start()

    @mainthread
    def update_ui_with_data(self, events_data):

        card_list = self.sm.get_screen('main').ids.card_list
        current_data = {card['event_id']: card for card in card_list.data}
        self.original_data = []  # Store original data here
        for event in events_data:

            event_id = event.id
            # Prepare the data for each card
            card_data = {
                'event_id': event_id,
                'widget_count': 0,
                'total_count': 0,
                'event_type': event.event_type,
                'reference_number': event.reference_number,
                'remarks': event.remarks,
                'image_count': event.image_count,
                'latitude': event.latitude,
                'longitude': event.longitude,
                'created_at': event.created_at,
                'sent_at': event.sent_at or '',
                'sent_picture': event.sent_picture
            }
            # Add or update card data
            if event_id in self.cards_dict:
                self.cards_dict[event_id].update(card_data)
            else:
                self.cards_dict[event_id] = card_data
                card_list.data.insert(0, card_data)  # Add to card_list data
            # Store the original data as the initial state
        self.original_data = list(card_list.data)
        # Calculate total count and update each card
        total_count = len(card_list.data)
        for index, card_data in enumerate(card_list.data):
            card_data['widget_count'] = index + 1
            card_data['total_count'] = total_count

I was doing some research and here's what i found:
"if you can pre-compute a sufficiently good approximation of the size of the item before displaying it, and put that value in the key_size key of your dict (that you can then update when the actual size is computed), then you can significantly improve the experience link: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6582"
I don't know how to implement it or if that suggestion would work. I'll appreciate any help you can give to me. Thanks

Pleas post a [mcve].
